# how to encrypt a string in aes waywith mbedtls?

Tags: c, encryption, polarssl, mbedtls

We all know that mbedtls library is a very lightweight c library. I want to use the library to encrypt a string. So I have a function like this:

aes_encrypt.h:

```
#ifndef AES_ENCRYPT_H
#define AES_ENCRYPT_H

#define BOOL int
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

extern const unsigned char key[16];

BOOL ENC_STR(unsigned char *plain, size_t plain_len, 
             unsigned char *cipher, size_t *cipher_len);
#endif
```

and the implementation:

```
const unsigned char KEY[16] = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03,
                                0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 
                                0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 
                                0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0F, 0xA0 };

BOOL ENC_STR(unsigned char *plain, size_t plain_len, unsigned char *cipher, size_t *cipher_len)
{
BOOL ret = FALSE;

// Prepare the cipher context
const mbedtls_cipher_info_t *cipher_info;
mbedtls_cipher_context_t cipher_ctx;
mbedtls_cipher_init(&cipher_ctx);

if ((cipher_info = mbedtls_cipher_info_from_type(AES_PARM)) == NULL)
{
    printf("Cipher Info ERR!\n");
    ret = -1;
    goto EXIT;
}

if ( (ret = mbedtls_cipher_setup(&cipher_ctx, cipher_info)) != 0)
{
    printf("Cipher Setup ERR!\n");
    goto EXIT;
}

if ( (ret = mbedtls_cipher_setkey(&cipher_ctx, KEY, cipher_info->key_bitlen, MBEDTLS_ENCRYPT)) != 0)
{
    printf("Cipher SetKey ERR!\n");
    goto EXIT;
}

// if ( (ret = mbedtls_cipher_set_padding_mode(&cipher_ctx, 1)) != 0) {
//     printf("Cipher SetPadding ERR!\n");
//     goto EXIT;
// }


if ( (ret = mbedtls_cipher_reset(&cipher_ctx)) != 0)
{
    printf("Cipher Reset ERR!\n");
    goto EXIT;
}

// encrypt
if ((ret = mbedtls_cipher_update(&cipher_ctx, plain, plain_len, cipher, cipher_len)) != 0) {
    printf("Cipher Update ERR!\n");
    goto EXIT;
}

EXIT:
    if (ret != TRUE) {
        char buf[1024] = {0};
        mbedtls_strerror(ret, buf, 1024);
        printf("Error Msg:\t%s\n", buf);
    }

    mbedtls_cipher_free(&cipher_ctx);
    return ret;
}
```

I call the function like bellow:

```
unsigned char *plain = (unsigned char*)"hello world";
size_t plain_len = 12;
unsigned char cipher[128] = {0};
size_t cipher_len = -1;
printf("the encrypt result is:\t%d\n", ENC_STR(plain, plain_len, cipher, &cipher_len));
```

And I get the err msg like below:

```
CIPHER - Decryption of block requires a full block
```

Can anyone help me out and explain what is the meaning of the error message? Thanks.

Comment: Needing a "full block" indicates that what you want encrypted is too short. Pad it.

Comment: But the doc (the mbedtls header file) said the default padding is pkcs7. Should I set it manually?

Comment: Look for MBEDTLS_CIPHER_MODE_WITH_PADDING in Cipher.h ..

Comment: .. as we all know

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen sry, I can't catch you? I have the read the Cipher.h. But I don't what to do to encrypt the string, not a block size of string but arbitrary size of string.

Comment: So have you actually looked for MBEDTLS_CIPHER_MODE_WITH_PADDING in the header ? You say another header say pkcs7 is default but yet this is commented out by default

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen Now I have use the function: `mbedtls_cipher_set_padding_mode(&cipher_ctx, MBEDTLS_PADDING_PKCS7)`, and I the got the Error: **CIPHER - Bad input parameters to function**. I am confused now. What is the wrong. And how to read the error message, is there a detail for it. Also @Yunnosch. Thanks you two.

Answer (score 1):

You need to complete your crypting with calling of `mbedtls_cipher_finish`.

The reason to `finish` comes from need to add padding, what is not done by `update`. The PKCS7 padding scheme (being used by default) always adds something even if the source data has `N * BlockSize` length.

https://tls.mbed.org/api/cipher_8h.html#a6678691c02cb3f1322b2179987bfffb2

Answer (score 0):

Explanation:

> CIPHER - Decryption of block requires a full block 
>   Can anyone help me out and explain what is the meaning of the error message?

AES is a [block cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher) it means it is implemented to encrypt 128 bit block at the time. Not more, not less.

So if you have source data shorter than a single block, you will need to use some [padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)) to ensure you prolong your data to a required length.

Generally to encrypt data of any length we use [mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation). There are some which do not require any padding (CTR, CFB, OFB, ..)

Still your encryption will be far from secure - you will need IV (salt) and [authentication tag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption).

> We all know that mbedtls library is a very lightweight c library

apparently the mbedtls already support multiple modes of operations, it's up to you to choose

Comment: I understand the theory of the AES. What I don't know is how to set padding in mbedtls library. When I use the mbedtls, should I encrypt the string just a block one time,  and then encrypt the next block  of the the string in next time?

Comment: @Andy I have to admin I don't know internals of mbedtls, but I will have a look on it.This is where these *modes of operation* come to play (how to encrypt a block at the time so it stays secure). Most of the libraries implement these modes out of box (so you don't need to care of the details and you can encrypt data of any length).  I assume the *mbedtls* does it on its own, just I don't know the parameters. If I find them, I wil include them

Answer (score 0):

You could either encrypt your full buffer using [`mbedtls_cipher_crypt()`](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls/blob/development/include/mbedtls/cipher.h#L678) , or cipher your buffer in several calls to [`mbedtls_cipher_update()`](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls/blob/development/include/mbedtls/cipher.h#L596).
To add padding, you should call [`mbedtls_cipher_set_padding_mode`](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls/blob/development/include/mbedtls/cipher.h#L520). However, as you can see from the [code](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls/blob/development/library/cipher.c#L172) the default padding scheme is PKCS7 , if `MBEDTLS_CIPHER_PADDING_PKCS7` is defined.
According to your code, it seems that you are using AES ECB( you haven't set any IV ). AES ECB does NOT support padding, and for security reasons, it accepts only AES BLOCK size of input (16 bytes). As mentioned below, you should consider using AES CBC for your operation ,as AES ECB is not secure for inputs more than 16 bytes, and your functions should be as generic as possible to support large strings as well.